# Deb packages stay with my username

Tags: debian, packages, dpkg

When I run the command:

> dpkg -b myprog

and

> sudo dpkg -i myprog.deb

The file in /usr/bin and /usr/share/, etc. stay with my username as owner and creator of the file when all the other are with root as owner and creator. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try chown'ing all the files to root before running `dpkg -b`.

Packages are normally created with `dpkg-buildpackage` because it can use `fakeroot` to insure all files are owned by root.

Comment: Thankyou very must. I did it with: "fakeroot dpkg -b qtgameoflife-1.2/"